A question of complex numbers involving inequality


$\begin {aligned}|a(z_2-z_3)+(z_3-z_1)|&\ge |a|\, |z_2-z_3|+|z_3-z_1|\text{(by triangle inequality)}\\
&\ge 2\sqrt a\cdot \sqrt{|z_2-z_3|\cdot|z_3-z_1|} \text{(by AM-GM inequality)}
\end{aligned}$
This the only thought came in my mind  looking in structure of the options.
Let $z_{1} z_{2} z_{3}$ be complex numbers such that $|z_{1}| = |z_{2}| = |z_{3}| = R$ and $z_{2} \ne z_3 $, then minimum value of $|az_{2} + (1 - a) z_{3} - z_{1}|$ is (where $a \in R$ )
$○ \frac1{(2R)}|z_{2} - z_{3}||z_{1} - z_{3}|$
$○ \frac1{(2R)}|z_{1} - z_{2}||z_{1} - z_{3}|$
$○ \frac1{(4R)}|z_{2} - z_{3}||z_{1} - z_{3}|$
$○\frac1{(4R)}|z_{1} - z_{2}||z_{1} - z_{3}|$


Triangle inequality is wrong. Correct form is: $ |a(z_2-z_3)+(z_3-z_1)| \leqslant |a|, |z_2-z_3|+|z_3-z_1|$

Okay that's my mistake. But I got nothing from that. So made a geometrical diagram we have to minimize the red vector

Solution:
The complex numbers $z_1, z_2, z_3$ can be seen as points in the complexe plane. So if we "translate" the question to geometry, we'll find that it basically says: we have $3$ points $A_1, A_2, A_3$, where $A_2$ and $A_3$ are different points. The linear combination of $z_2$ and $z_3$ can be seen as a point on the straight line $l$ passing the $2$ points $A_2$ and $A_3$. So $|az_{2} + (1 - a) z_{3} - z_1|$ can be translated as the distance between $A_1$ and a point on the straight line $l$.
So the minimum of that will be the distance from $A_1$ to the straight line $l$.
So we have something like this:

The minimum stands for $|A_1H|$, and we can see half of the product $|A_1H|\cdot |A_2A_3|$ is the area of the triangle $A_1A_2A_3$. Draw the midpoint $M$ of $A_2A_3$, and we have
$$ S_{\triangle A_1A_2A_3} = \frac12 |A_1H|\cdot |A_2A_3| = |A_1H|\cdot |MA_3| = |A_1H|\cdot R\sin{\angle MOA_3}.$$
However we know that $\angle MOA_3 = \angle A_2A_1A_3$ (the red angles), and that:
$$ S_{\triangle A_1A_2A_3} = \frac12 |A_1A_2|\cdot|A_1A_3| \sin{\angle A_2A_1A_3} = \frac12 |A_1A_2|\cdot|A_1A_3| \sin{\angle MOA_3}. $$
So we obtain:
$$ |A_1H|\cdot R\sin{\angle MOA_3} = \frac12 |A_1A_2|\cdot|A_1A_3| \sin{\angle MOA_3}, $$
and thus:
$$ |A_1H| = \frac{1}{2R} |A_1A_2|\cdot|A_1A_3| $$
which translates back to the language of complex numbers as:
$$ \min_{a\in\mathbb{R}}{|az_{2} + (1 - a) z_{3} - z_1|} = \frac{1}{2R} |z_1 - z_2|\cdot|z_1 - z_3|. $$
